# BackgroundColour program using AndEngine crashing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

For a school project myself and a group have been told to develop and Android app. We decided to use AndEngine for our engine and tried out a basic app. My partner and I created a program that would simply make the background blue and it worked, but as soon as we ran it at home on the emulator and our android devices we would get a "has stopped responding" error. We used the up to date Eclipse on both machines and compiled the programs in both 2.3 and 4.0. We receive no errors when running the emulator at first, but as soon as the program starts it crashes. Anyone have an idea as to why this might be?

Here is the code

```
package first.test;

import org.anddev.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions.ScreenOrientation;
import org.anddev.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.scene.background.ColorBackground;
import org.anddev.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;



public class HelloWorldActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
private Camera mCamera;

@Override
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new         RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera));
}

@Override
public void onLoadResources() {

}

@Override
public Scene onLoadScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
    final Scene scene = new Scene(1);
    scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0, 0, 0.8784f));
    return scene;
}

@Override
public void onLoadComplete() {

}
}
```

Comment: Stack trace or it didn't happen ;)